# Four non-coplanar points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ determine an unique sphere.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Show that four non-coplanar points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ determine an unique sphere.

I have no idea how to solve this exercise. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the two-dimensional result, that three non-conlinear points determine a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The equation of a sphere of center $C=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and radius $r$ is:
$$
(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2+(z-\gamma)^2=r^2
$$
that becomes
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2+ax+by+cz+d=0
$$
with
$$
a=-2\alpha \quad b=-2\beta \quad c=-2\gamma \quad d=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-r^2
$$

so if we have four points, substituting the coordinates of these points in the equation we find  a linear system of four equations in four unknowns $a,b,c,d$ that has one solution if the four points are not coplanar (look at its determinant).

Comment: what property satisfy 4 points $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$,  $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$,  $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$,  $(x_4, y_4, z_4)$ not coplanar?

Comment: the determinant of the system is $\triangle= v_1\cdot (v_2\times v_3)+v_1\cdot (v_4\times v_2)+v_1\cdot (v_3\times v_4)+v_2\cdot (v_4\times v_3)$ with $v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1), v_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2),  v_3=(x_3,y_3,z_3), v_4=(x_4,y_4,z_4)$. How $v_1, v_2,v_3, v_4$ are not coplanar then every product $v_1\cdot (v_2\times v_3)$, $v_1\cdot (v_4\times v_2)$, $v_1\cdot (v_3\times v_4)$, $v_2\cdot (v_4\times v_3)$  is nonzero but, why $\triangle \neq 0$?

Comment: look at : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Coplanar.html.  The determinant  that gives the volume is  the determinant of the system.

Comment: know where I can find the proof $\left|
                  \begin{array}{cccc}
                    x_1 & y_1 & z_1 & 1 \\
                    x_2 & y_2 & z_2 & 1 \\
                    x_3 & y_3 & z_3 & 1 \\
                    x_4 & y_4 & z_4 &1 \\
                  \end{array}
                \right|\neq 0$ iff $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2)$,  $P_3(x_3,y_3,z_3)$, $P_4(x_4,y_4,z_4)$ are not coplanar? Thanks!

Comment: I see that you have post another related question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483478/not-coplanar-points-in-mathbbr3-if-and-only-if-its-determinant-is-nonzero/1483644#1483644), so, now, I understand your problem. I've given an answer to the related question that I hope solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Consider the perpendicular bisector planes of three segments joining couples of points. Those planes intersect at a point that is the center of a sphere passing through the four points. And this is the only sphere having such property.