# Determine 4th vertice of tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, analytic-geometry

I have tetrahedron of volume 1, with vertices $(1, 2, 3)$ , $(2, 3, 4)$ and $(2, 4, 5)$. The assignment tells me to determine the 4th. It lies on line $(x, y, z) = t(1, 1, 2)$.

I know the volume of a tetrahedron is $ V = \frac{1}{6} determinant|4 (vertices)|$
Since I know this is supposed to be 1, I thought maybe I can set one of the vertices inside to x, y, z and decide what they should be?? Since I know the line it should be on (x, y, z) = t(1, 1, 2) I know I should probably be able to do something with this information too, but what?? I calculated the (x, y, z) with the determinant, atlest tried to and got it to be $(x, y, z) = (0, \frac{1}{6}+z, y-\frac{1}{6})$ Buuut I have no idea if this is somewhat right. So can someone help me. How can I from this information find the 4th vertices of the tetrahedron??

The excercise is in linear algebra.

Comment: FYI, there is no such as a 'vertice'.  The singular of 'vertices' is 'vertex'.

Comment: Ok I see, well english is not my first language. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The [volume](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html) is:
$$V=\dfrac{1}{6}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
                     1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
                     2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
                     2 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
                     t & t & 2t &1 \\
                   \end{array}
                 \right|=1 $$ 
so you have the equation in $t$
$$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
                     1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
                     2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
                     2 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
                     t & t & 2t &1 \\
                   \end{array}
                 \right|=6 $$

Comment: Can I ask, I know from videos and other examples on the internet, but why do we use 1111 in the end? Is it to make the matrix balanced?? :)

Comment: And is there any danger of using the one's, my teacher hinted something like it could be a bit of a danger but I did not understand how and why, and can we always do this?

Comment: One more question of it is ok, I got the answer that t = -1, could it then be right to say the 4th vertix is (-1, -1, -2) when I have solved for t? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can see my answer to:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483478/not-coplanar-points-in-mathbbr3-if-and-only-if-its-determinant-is-nonzero/1483644#1483644, where it is shown that the absolute value of the determinant gives the volume of a parallelepiped with vertices in four points, and the volume of the tetrahedron is $1/6$ of this. Someone use a different position for the $1$ terms, and this can change the sign of the determinant, but if you consider its absolute value the result is the same.

Comment: Your calculus seams wrong. Calculating the  determinant you have that the equation, with absolute value, is $|1-t|=6$ that has solutions $t=7$ or $t=-5$.

Comment: Ok thanks , I'll check it again.